# compressing selected image file/taken from camera

Tags: java, android

trying to let users add profile pictures, but I want to compress the image file before sending it to the server.

How can i compress the:

> File imageFile = new File(resultUri.getPath());

Tried and searched but couldn't get to work

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                btnConfirm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        File imageFile = new File(resultUri.getPath());

                        progressDialog.show();
                        AndroidNetworking.upload("https://myweb.com/uploadImg.php")
                                .addMultipartFile("image", imageFile)
```

Would love to get some advice, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Search for Bitmap compression that is using FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
            selectedImage);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
try {
    stream.close();
    stream = null;
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```